# Python string has a character that is present in Linux but missing in Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, string

This is the first question I'm posting so please pardon my ignorance. I am using python to write into files and then read them. Using the usual suspects (`file.read()`, `file.write()`)

The code is being run on both windows and Linux.
A particular string I'm reading, say `str` is giving a length of 6 on Windows, while it is giving a length of 7 on Linux.
I tried exploring what this magic character is but it turns out I cant print it!
If i try printing `str`, it gives the same results on Windows and Linux.
If i try printing `str[6]` on Linux, it prints blank!

I have verified that it is not a whitespace or newline(\n) character. I am even unable to print the ascii value of this character. Are there characters out there without ascii values?

I have found that `strip()` function eliminates this magic character but I am still curious as to what it is.

Comment: Try `repr()` on it. You will maybe see `\r` in Linux, but not in Windows.

Comment: What error do you have at print(ord(char))? (I hope you take care of bytes/unicode/string problem, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, newline is "\r\n", while on Linux it is "\n". This is why there is a character count discrepancy.